# How to have the logon screen span over 3 monitors Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, login

I have a windows 7 machine and I'm using eyefinity to user 3 monitors on this computer.
The only thing that is bothering me is that when I boot the computer and get to the logon screen where I have to input my password, only the center monitor is "active", the other 2 monitors are on but their screens are just black.

So basically I was wondering with it was possible to have the logon screen span over all 3 monitors? Kinda like a multi monitor wallpaper.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a duplicate, Eyefinity can merge multiple screens into one with a higher resolution - probably the driver isn't loaded on the logon screen and two other screens are treated differently. Still, the possible duplicate may be worth giving it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a fixed resolution range for the log on screen which makes it possible to be displayed in max to max 1 monitor of any resolution.
I am afraid what you ask is not possible unless YOU edit the log on screen graphics.